# Find the tallest element within a set

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, loops

I am using Bootstrap row classes `col-sm-4 inside`. I need to find the "title" `div` with the greatest height and set the same `height` for each title within the same row.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="title">Blah-blah-blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="title">More Blah-blah-blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="title">Blah-blah-blah</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="title">Blah-blah-blah and Blah-blah-blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="title">More Blah-blah-blah</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="title">Blah-blah-blah</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use any of the css display table-row/table-cell options instead of going down a javascript route for this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.row').each(function()
{
    var max = 0;
    $(this).find('.title').each(function(){
        if($(this).height() > max)
            max = $(this).height();
    });

    $(this).find('.title').css('height', max);

});
```

Thats the simple way to do it. You may need to adjust to factor in breakpoints for media queries and may want to be more specific with selectors to avoid accidentally factoring anything elsewhere. Also, some will argue using `for` instead of `$.each` to iterate but with this size you wont notice any lag.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are trying to do?

```
$(".row").each(function(row){
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $(row).find(".title").each(function(title){
        maxHeight = Math.max($(title).height(), maxHeight);
    });
    $(row).find(".title").css({height: maxHeight+'px'});
}
```

Comment: Seriously... annoying

Comment: I'm plussing to negate the drive by downvote but really, why? OP asked for javascript, jquery, and this solution would do it. What gives?

Comment: Actually I like yours more with the Math.max. ever done a benchmark on max vs longer conditional? course not cause it would be a small margin. I wonder which is technically more efficient

Comment: I haven't.. but my guess is that the difference is negligible